# Referencing a range: Run-time error '1004' object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

A macro to fill blank spaces in a selection. It does not like my rng variable, even with Set and range declaration.

```
Sub fill2()  

Dim Rng As Range      

Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Range here", Type:=8)  
    ActiveCell.Range("Rng").Select  
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=+R[-1]C"  
End Sub
```

Comment: `"rng"` is text, not the `rng` variable. But don't use `rng` within a `Range` call, and don't use `Select` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Excel native features or by VBA

As you asked for VBA.

**VBA code:**

```
Sub fill2()
    Dim evalRange As Range

    Set evalRange = Application.InputBox("Range here", Type:=8)
    On Error Resume Next
    evalRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

---

**Excel native features:**

1. Select the range
2. Press: F5 key
3. Click: Special
4. Select: Blanks
5. Type: `=`
6. Select the cell above with your mouse
7. Press: Ctrl + Enter

Comment: Thanks yes I know it does this in excel native, that is why I have the macro, I get sick of pressing f5 etc I have to do it about 90 times.

Comment: Works beautifully, your a champion.  Thanks